# Como adiciono uma imagem de fundo em um Jframe?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Estou a tentar mudar a imagem de fundo do meu JFrame, mas estou a ter dificuldades. Aqui esta o código:

```
public class teste_tamagotchi extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                final Image backgroundImage = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Bibliotecas\\Imagens\\galaxy-wallpaper-11.jpg"));
                setContentPane(new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
                    @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                        g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

E tenho o seguinte erro:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   setContentPane(Container) from the type JFrame

Comment: Pode adicionar um **[mcve]** do seu jframe?

Comment: irei editar o meu código, tudo bem ?

Answer (score 3):

Você não pode fazer referencia a um método não estático dentro de um estático.

No caso do código, `setContentPane()` não pode ser chamado dentro do método main, pois ele pertence a uma instância do `JFrame`.

Crie um construtor ou um método que construa seu `JFrame` dentro da classe, e dentro do main apenas instancie sua janela:

```
public class teste_tamagotchi extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */

public teste_tamagotchi(){

    try {
        final Image backgroundImage = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Bibliotecas\\Imagens\\galaxy-wallpaper-11.jpg"));
        setContentPane(new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
            @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           teste_tamagotchi t = new teste_tamagotchi();
           t.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Outra dica é evitar usar nomes iniciados com letra minúsculas como nomes de classe, há uma [**convenção**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) para isso indicando que você deve iniciar sempre com letra maiúscula o nome de uma classe, seguindo padrão [**CamelCase**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).

Comment: @Paulo a resposta lhe atendeu?