# Como manipular o local dos JLabels, tendo um papel de parede?

Tags: java, swing

Estou tentando fazer um app que tenha um papel de parede, mas não consigo mudar de posição os `JButton` ou `JLabel`. Só consigo se não tiver um plano de fundo.

Segue meu código:

```
public class teste extends JFrame{

public teste(){

JLabel titulo1 = new JLabel("Testes de local1");

JLabel titulo2 = new JLabel("Testes de local2");
//

ImageIcon imagem = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/fotos/1.png"));

JLabel background = new JLabel(imagem);

//
setLayout(new BorderLayout());

background.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,titulo2);

add(background);

background.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

background.add(titulo1);
//
setVisible(true);

setSize(400, 400);

setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

setTitle("Teste");



}
}
```

Comment: Como assim? Pode editar e explicar melhor o problema?

Comment: Desculpe, não é JButton, são os dois JLabels que quero manipular

Comment: Veja essa resposta, ela te atende: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/205296/28595  se não entender algo, avisa ai que explico.

Comment: Eu percebi que encontro minha solução la, mas n consigo entender o código. O java ainda é muito novo para mim, agradeço se puder ajudar!

Comment: o background é pra ser aplicado a jframe ne? Sem se preocupar com redimensionamento nem nada? Essa é mais simples: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/158841/28595

Comment: Exatamente isso

Comment: Ainda assim, consigo fazer o comando, você pode pegar meu código e formata-lo para que funcione?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evite utilizar `JLabel` para adicionar background em tela, pois ele é um componente comum e não vai permitir você sobrepor outros componentes sobre si.

A forma mais recomendada de se fazer isso é criar um componente do tipo `Container` como `JPanel`, ou que seja um [container top level](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html),  e sobrescrever o método [`paintComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent-java.awt.Graphics-). Alem de preencher o fundo, ainda vai te permitir adicionar outros inúmeros componentes e posicioná-los como quiser:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TesteBG extends JFrame {

    public TesteBG() {

        JLabel titulo1 = new JLabel("Testes de local1");

        JLabel titulo2 = new JLabel("Testes de local2");
        //
        BackgroundPanel bgPanel = new BackgroundPanel();
        //
        bgPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        bgPanel.add(titulo1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        bgPanel.add(titulo2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setContentPane(bgPanel);

        setSize(400, 400);

        setTitle("Teste");

        setVisible(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel {

        Image imagem;

        public BackgroundPanel() {

            try {

                imagem = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/fotos/1.png"));

            } catch (IOException e) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possivel ler a imagem !");

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.drawImage(imagem, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new TesteBG();
        });
    }
}
```

Perceba que também é recomendado configurar este painel como rootPane da tela através do método [`setContentPane()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setContentPane-java.awt.Container-). A partir dai, tudo que você adicionar na tela deve ser adicionado ao painel e não diretamente na tela, para não ficar partes sem background.

Há uma forma mais complexa, porém mais efetiva de aplicar imagem de fundo a uma tela, sem ficar preso ao tamanho da tela ou da imagem, se quiser saber como, está bem explicado [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/205296/28595).

Comment: Ainda assim, dessa forma não consigo manipular da forma que gostaria, por exemplo: não é possível colocar os JLabels no canto inferior ou superior direito e nem mesmo no centro. Eu gostaria de ter controle total

Comment: @gui22222 isso é outro problema diferente do relatado na pergunta. A resposta atende ao problema de por um background e permitir que você adicione componentes com ele por baixo, esse problema ai é devido a layout manager. Você pode dar uma lida no link e ver qual melhor te atende: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: @gui22222 da forma que expliquei, é possivel fazer qualquer coisa dentro do painel, pra isso, você precisa ter dominio de layouts, por isso é importante ver o link acima.

Comment: Entendi! Consegui resolver meu problema também, obrigado.